# 救えたはずのもの... (lots of unaccounted もの)

Tags: particle-も, particle-まで

I have a real patchy understanding of this sentence in Danganronpav3.

The speaker is 星 (Hoshi) and is incredibly cynical in contrast to the main character's optimism. He sometimes explains things in a difficult to understand way:

> 理想{りそう｝だけじゃ救｛すく｝えるものも救えない。救えたはずのものまで見捨｛みす｝てるハメになりかねない。

Attempted translation: "Some things can't be saved just through ideals. Sometimes even what you thought was saved can end up lost."

My assumptions are:

- The じゃ is a colloquial では
- That もの is 物 and not 者.
- That the use of も implies some cases were in the positive.
- That the まで is being used as an "even in the case of

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: 救えたはず means "should be able to save". So the sentence is saying that sometimes you cannot even save what you could have saved (with actual effort), if you only use ideals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regarding the first sentence, yes, this じゃ is a colloquial では, and this もの is basically 物 (thing) in general, although it may include people as well. も in 救えるものも means "even". The literal translation is "Only with ideals, you cannot save even what you can save." But your translation attempt seems fine to me.

Regarding the second sentence, 救えたはずのもの is a noun phrase meaning "something you could have saved", which is the object of 見捨てる. まで, meaning "even", *replaces* を and が.

> 救えたはずのものまで見捨てるハメになりかねない。
>   You may end up abandoning even what you could have saved.